# How to point webpack to a specific node_modules folder

Tags: web, webpack, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to build a `grpc` web client and I need to pack the code to resolve the `require` statements.

I have compiled the `protos` to `js`  and it works if I have them in the current folder where I have installed the `node modules`.

The problem is if I have the `compiled proto` in some other place and I require them from there, `webpack` looks for the `node modules` in that path.

From my `client.js`

**working version:**

```
const {StopRequest, StopReply} = require('./work_pb.js');
```

**Problematic version:**

```
const {StopRequest, StopReply} = require('../../../messages/proto/output/work_pb.js');
```

In this last case it looks for the `node modules` in `../../../messages/proto/output/`.
The `node modules` are installed in the current path where my `client.js` is and from where I ran `npx webpack client.js`.

```
ERROR in /home/xxx/yyy/zzz/messages/proto/output/work_pb.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'google-protobuf' in '/home/xxx/yyy/zzz/messages/proto/output'
 @ /home/xxx/yyy/zzz/messages/proto/output/work_pb.js 11:11-37
 @ ./client.js
```

How do I tell `webpack` to look in the current path for the node modules and not in the path of the compiled proto?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can specify [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules) to customize the directory, where Webpack searches for modules with absolute import paths:

```
// inside webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'), 'node_modules']
  }
};
```

This will let `node_modules` inside your project root (where webpack config resides) take precedence over the default setting `"node_modules"`, which resolves paths via [node module resolution](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) algorithm.

More infos: [Webpack docs: Module Resolution](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/)

Comment: Even better.. I moved `package.json` and `webpack.config.js` outside of my `app` folder (one level up) and I can still run `npm install` and `npx webpack client.js` from the `app` folder. I guess it checks up the hierarchy.

Comment: Yeah, `npm install` will traverse up to the nearest package.json or node_modules, if not found in cwd. Concerning webpack, I am not so sure, what defaults it will use then. I think, it's worth to make everything as explicit and comprehensible as possible. That's the reason why I prefer to pass in the config via `--config`.